# How to inspect styles with ionic and sass

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

In ionic 1, when you run "ionic serve" it launches in the browser, and when you right-click and inspect an element, it would tell you the name of the stylesheet and the exact line number in that stylesheet with styles affecting the element. You can then find it and edit it in a very easy way.

Now in Ionic 4, when you run "ionic serve", it launches the app in the browser just like before. However, when you inspect an element it gives you the line number in the compiled runtime css file (something like line 20732) instead of the line number in the actual app.scss file you are editing your styles from.

I understand the logic behind why it's doing that, but is there a way to get the browser to tell me the line number in the app.scss file? Do I need to set up a new test environment or run another command other than "ionic serve"?

*app.scss file highlighting line number*
[image]

*inspector showing line number after "ionic serve" command*

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you give us a code to help you better.

Comment: I don't use ionic, but it sounds like it's not producing a sourcemap. Take a look in the Ionic documentation if there's a way to turn it on.

Comment: @Yoarthur I just updated the question with pictures. I hope that helps.

Comment: @anderssonola I tried looking for what you suggested, but found nothing that came close to what I meant. :(

Comment: Are you using Gulp to compile the scss-files, you should be able to edit the config of the sass task ?

Comment: @anderssonola no I'm not. Just running the regular "ionic serve" command. How would I go about doing this?